# How to inherit @JsonCreator information

Tags: java, jackson

As of jackson-2.6, `required` property is only used for `@JsonCreator`. I have two class `A` and `B`. `A` has a required property and `B` is inherited from `A`.

When we use `@JsonCreator`, we can't get properties information from super class.See the following code, `B` doesn't check required property 'a'.

If we have many required properties, how to inherit? I don't want to repeat to write `@JsonProperty`.

```
public class App {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    ObjectMapper objMapper = new ObjectMapper();

    String jsonA = "{}";              // miss 'a'
    try {
      objMapper.readValue(jsonA, A.class);
    } catch (IOException e) {
      System.out.println("A: Should get exception");  // happen
      e.printStackTrace();
    }

    String jsonB = "{\"b\":\"B\"}";   // miss 'a'
    try {
      objMapper.readValue(jsonB, B.class);
    } catch (IOException e) {
      System.out.println("B: Should get exception"); // not happen
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}


class A {
  private String a;

  public A() {
  }

  @JsonCreator
  public A(@JsonProperty(value = "a", required = true) String a) {
    this.a = a;
  }

  public String getA() {
    return a;
  }
}

class B extends A {
  private String b;

  @JsonCreator
  public B(@JsonProperty(value = "b", required = true) String b) {
    this.b = b;
  }

  public String getB() {
    return b;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Constructors are not inherited. in your example, B is calling parameter-less constructor `A()`. Note when you remove `A()` from `A` class, solution will not compile.

In your case, when you need class `B` to have property a and b you need to have that properties as constructor parameters for `B`

```
 @JsonCreator
  public B(@JsonProperty(value = "a", required = true) String a,
           @JsonProperty(value = "b", required = true) String b,
) {
    super(a);
    this.b = b;
  }
```

You may reuse parametrized constructor `A(String a)` by calling it from `B(String a, String b)`.

You may also not use constructor and annotate fields `a` and `b` as `@JsonProperty`.
Then it should work without any constructors or any additional code.

Comment: Thanks. But my trouble is that I have many `required`, I don't want to repeat to write `@JsonProperty ` many times.If I don't use constructor and `@JsonCreator`, I can't ensure that 'a' exist.

Comment: You may write @JsonProperty(required = true) directly at each field.
Such way properties required will be inherited.

But you will not have validation at constructor level (for building object manually). For that, you need constructor in each class.

For Jackson you may add parameterless private constructor to each class.

Comment: Since jackson-2.6, `required` property is only used for `@JsonCreator`.